# Transparent cursor after scrolling | IOS | JS

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

I noticed a strange bug, but I don't know how to fix it. If you scroll past the element (overscrolling), and at the moment when the scroll is restored to its initial state, programmatically focus on the input, then the color of the cursor is transparent.

I have a list of elements and at the beginning there is a search that renders another list on clicking on it. And it turns out that if you focus on it immediately after the scroll, then the cursor is simply not visible.

The site is launched through WKWebView, so there is access to native code if necessary to solve the problem.

Tried to toggle **overflow** on click.
Tried toggling **-webkit-overflow-scrolling**.
I tried to forcefully install **tintColor **in WKWebView.
Change the methods of clicking on the block: **click, touchstart, touchend**.
Tried to force redraw document.clientWidth.
What I have under toggle:
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
document.body.style.overflow = "auto";

document.body.style.setProperty("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "auto");
document.body.style.setProperty("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "touch");

**UPD:**
Made a reproducible example. If you scroll to the very bottom quickly and when the gray box rises above the input (I call this state "bounced"), then when you click on the input you will not have a cursor.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 50vh;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
    max-height: 400px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
}
.fake-content {
  min-height: 2000px;
    background: grey;
    width: 100%;
}
input {
  position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    min-height: 80px;
}
body {overflow: hidden; margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='fake-content'></div>
  </div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```